# Access Oracle database from react native(firebase cloud functions)

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

im trying to access the database fom the company i work, but dont know how to do it..
Im creating an App in React Native and firebase, im using firestore as core, but i need to access an Oracle database that is hosted by the company, for some data.
I was thinking in accessing it inside the firebase functions with something like oracledb from node, but dont know if it will work, as the docs say cloud functions only works with mysql postgresql and sql server.
Do i have to make an backend only for accessing that?
Any help is apreciated, many thanks!

Edit: Also, i have to access it from tsnames.ora, if it changes anything.

Comment: If your Oracle database is accessible from the internet, it should be callable from Cloud Functions too. And since Cloud Functions are fairly thin wrappers around Node.js, you'll want to start looking at [how to access Oracle from Node.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+access+Oracle+from+Node.js).
--- "the docs say cloud functions only works with mysql postgresql and sql server" Can you provide a link to where in what documentation is says that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure thing, here goes https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs.
The database is accessible through tsnames.ora.

Comment: That documentation is about Google Cloud **SQL**, which is a product to host managed instances of MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQL Server on Google Cloud Platform. The limit on the DBMS platforms available there is not related to what DBMS systems you can call from Google Cloud **Functions**.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you quoted is about Google Cloud **SQL**, which is a product to host managed instances of MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQL Server on Google Cloud Platform. The limit on the DBMS platforms available there is not related to what DBMS systems you can call from Google Cloud **Functions**.

If your Oracle database is accessible from the internet, it should be callable from Cloud Functions too. And since Cloud Functions are fairly thin wrappers around Node.js, you'll want to start looking at [how to access Oracle from Node.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+access+Oracle+from+Node.js).

Comment: Hi @Frank Van Puffelen, thanks for the answer. I followed your instruction and managed to make oracledb work with firebase functions, but only in development, when i deploy my functions i get the error: Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/workspace/instantclient_21_7/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". referring to instant client from oracle. In localhost it works, but it seems i cant make it with functions in deploy. Is there any easy workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed you already opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280795/oracle-instant-client-inside-firebase-functions) for that Victor, so I recommend leaving this new problem there. The approach outlined in my answer should still be the path to follow: 1. Get it working in a local Node.js environment, 2. Then try to do the same on Cloud Functions.

Comment: As unfortunate as it is, your answer says its possible to use oracledb in firebase functions, but to use it there we need to change envoronmental system variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH..
So if its not possible, the doc you linked dont explain how to do it, resulting in not being able to use oracledb in functions.