# Oracle instant client inside Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to setup an oracledb connection with firebase functions, as seen in this fórum : [Access Oracle database from react native(firebase cloud functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182707/access-oracle-database-from-react-nativefirebase-cloud-functions).

I followed Frank, that had the kindness to help me, but i could get only so far as to make it work in development, because there is a problem with oracle instant client and firebase functions. In localhost, the functions read the binaries no problem but when i deploy i get the error:

**Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html You must have 64-bit Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async /workspace/lib/index.js:43:28 at async /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:411:26 { errorNum: 0, offset: 0 }**

Do i have any workaround in firebase functions or i really have to migrate to another solution?
Thanks for helping!

I tried putting the instantclient folder in like all places inside functions, tried to make a https.onRequest call, but nothing works.

**Edit:** Managed to solve half the issue: Im running my code in a Windows machine and the config to it is just the libDir from oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: //path to the instantclient }).
In firebase functions is Linux, so i needed a different instantclient for it, but now im with a new error:

**DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/workspace/src/config/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so: file too short"**

After some search i found that oracledb.initOracleClient does not work properly for linux, and some configs are necessary. Follow the docs from it:

"On Linux, ensure a libclntsh.so file exists. On macOS ensure a libclntsh.dylib file exists. Node-oracledb will not directly load libclntsh..XX.1 files in libDir. Note other libraries used by libclntsh are also required.

On Linux, using libDir is only useful for forcing initOracleClient() to immediately load the Oracle Client libraries because those libraries still need to be in the operating system search path, such as from running ldconfig or set in the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH."

I dont know what to do now to make it work, can anyone with more experience in this matter help me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec im using oracledb, is node-oracledb a diferent package?

Comment: Edit: Yes im using it, i did all the configs and oracledb runs prefectly in localhost, the problem is in Firebase functions, i believe..

Comment: The error '/workspace/src/config/instantclient_21_8/libclntsh.so: file too short' sounds like you might still have the wrong Instant Client, or it didn't transfer properly.  But you will still need to work out how to set the library search path. 
 One different application architecture would be to look at moving to Python, since the python-oracledb driver doesn't need Oracle Instant Client.